# Error when I try to run an executable file while loading libz.so.1 library

Tags: debian, executable

I can't run the executable file because of the `libz.so.1` library.

I have already installed the `zlib1g_1.2.11.dfsg-1_amd64.deb` package, but the error still appears. How can I do to solve this? This is the output of the terminal.

```
user@debian:~/Games/Undertale$ ./runner 
./runner: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Update**: I successfully installed the library above using `sudo apt install lib32z1` but there are another libraries that I can't find it. This is the output of the `ldd` command:

```
user@debian:~/Games/Undertale$ ldd runner 
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7fb3000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib32/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7e18000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib32/libz.so.1 (0xf7df9000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => not found
    libGL.so.1 => not found
    libopenal.so.1 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf7d2a000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib32/librt.so.1 (0xf7d1f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7cfe000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf7cf8000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libXext.so.6 => not found
    libX11.so.6 => not found
    libXrandr.so.2 => not found
    libGLU.so.1 => not found
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7cd8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf7afa000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7fb5000)
```

How can I find the missing libraries?

(Note: The executable is a i386 binary but the system is amd64)

Comment: Is `runner` actually an amd64 (x86_64) binary? What does `file ./runner` say?

Comment: @steeldriver The file is a i386 binary but my system is amd64, I have already managed to install the library successfully using `sudo apt install lib32z1` but there's some issues with another libraries. (I update the question adding the `ldd` command)